# makefile multiple definition errors

Tags: c

Following is the error I get when I run my makefile:

```
 gcc ./bin/sortMe.o ./bin/compare_id_ascending.o ./bin/compare_id_descending.o ./bin/compare_name_ascending.o ./bin/compare_name_descending.o ./bin/compare_money_ascending.o ./bin/compare_money_descending.o -o sortMe
./bin/compare_money_descending.o: In function `compare_money_ascending':
compare_money_descending.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `compare_money_ascending'
./bin/compare_money_ascending.o:compare_money_ascending.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
./bin/sortMe.o: In function `main':
sortMe.c:(.text+0x59f): undefined reference to `compare_money_descending'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:11: recipe for target 'sortMe' failed
make: *** [sortMe] Error 1
```

This is what my makefile looks like:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -I$(IDIR)

IDIR = ./include/
SDIR = ./src/
BDIR = ./bin/

all : sortMe

sortMe : $(BDIR)sortMe.o $(BDIR)compare_id_ascending.o $(BDIR)compare_id_descending.o $(BDIR)compare_name_ascending.o $(BDIR)compare_name_descending.o $(BDIR)compare_money_ascending.o $(BDIR)compare_money_descending.o
    $(CC) $(BDIR)sortMe.o $(BDIR)compare_id_ascending.o $(BDIR)compare_id_descending.o $(BDIR)compare_name_ascending.o $(BDIR)compare_name_descending.o $(BDIR)compare_money_ascending.o $(BDIR)compare_money_descending.o -o $@

$(BDIR)sortMe.o : $(SDIR)sortMe.c $(IDIR)compareElements.h $(IDIR)compareFunctions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SDIR)sortMe.c -o $@

$(BDIR)compare_id_ascending.o : $(SDIR)compare_id_ascending.c $(IDIR)compareElements.h $(IDIR)compareFunctions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SDIR)compare_id_ascending.c -o $@

$(BDIR)compare_id_descending.o : $(SDIR)compare_id_descending.c $(IDIR)compareElements.h $(IDIR)compareFunctions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SDIR)compare_id_descending.c -o $@

$(BDIR)compare_name_ascending.o : $(SDIR)compare_name_ascending.c $(IDIR)compareElements.h $(IDIR)compareFunctions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SDIR)compare_name_ascending.c -o $@

$(BDIR)compare_name_descending.o : $(SDIR)compare_name_descending.c $(IDIR)compareElements.h $(IDIR)compareFunctions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SDIR)compare_name_descending.c -o $@

$(BDIR)compare_money_ascending.o : $(SDIR)compare_money_ascending.c $(IDIR)compareElements.h $(IDIR)compareFunctions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SDIR)compare_money_ascending.c -o $@

$(BDIR)compare_money_descending.o : $(SDIR)compare_money_descending.c $(IDIR)compareElements.h $(IDIR)compareFunctions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SDIR)compare_money_descending.c -o $@

run :
    ./sortMe

clean :
    rm ./bin/*.o ./sortMe
```

These errors really confuse me and would appreciate it if anyone pointed out my mistake.
Also, do I have to add $(BDIR) $(SDIR) and $(IDIR) everywhere I declare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages:

```
./bin/compare_money_descending.o: In function `compare_money_ascending':
compare_money_descending.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `compare_money_ascending'
```

say that the source file `compare_money_descending.c` contains a definition of `compare_money_ascending` although a prior definition of it already exists. Since the file name `compare_money_descending.c` suggests it contains a function named `compare_money_descending` but we are getting an error about `compare_money_ascending`, it is likely the mistake is that `compare_money_descending.c` contains a definition using a function name of `compare_money_ascending` where `compare_monehy_descending` was intended. Quite likely you copied and pasted source code to use as a new function but forget to change the name.

The second message:

```
sortMe.c:(.text+0x59f): undefined reference to `compare_money_descending'
```

tells us the program does not contain a definition of `compare_money_descending`, which tends to confirm the above hypothesis.